# XSD Schema Unique Constraint not Working for Numeric Values?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, altova, oxygenxml

Consider this XSD Schema, resulting in the following graph

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:schema xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:target="http://www.url.com/validation" 
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <s:element name="myObjects" type="typeObjects">
        <s:unique name="uniqueObjectId">
            <s:selector xpath="myObject"/>
            <s:field xpath="id"/>
        </s:unique>
    </s:element>
    <s:complexType name="typeObjects">
        <s:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <s:element name="myObject">
                <s:complexType>
                    <s:complexContent>
                        <s:extension base="typeObject"/>
                    </s:complexContent>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
    <s:complexType name="typeObject">
        <s:sequence>
            <s:element name="id" type="s:int"/>
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:schema>
```

[image: still passes validation]

Note the unique constraint set on the "id" element, typed as s:int.

The following instance XML still validates, even having the same `<id>1</id>` twice!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<myObjects 
    xmlns:target="http://www.url.ch/validation" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="unique.xsd">

    <myObject>
        <id>1</id>
    </myObject>

    <myObject>
        <id>1</id>
    </myObject>
</myObjects>
```

I can force the fail condition if I change the element type to **s:string**

This will **not** validate the instance XML anymore, as expected:
[image: fails validation as expected]

I tried the validation in oXygen XML and ALtova XML Spy with the same result respectively.

The question is obviously if this a bug or a known limitation in the unique constraint implementation of XSD?

Answer (score 0):

Your xsd looks good and I confirmed it with oxygen. I got the expected error:

```
cvc-identity-constraint.4.1: Duplicate unique value [1] declared for identity 
constraint "uniqueObjectId" of element "myObjects".
```

I see that validation works fine for SAXON-EE 9.6.0.7

```
Non-unique value found for constraint uniqueObjectId: 1
```

and for other engines.

Try checking your validation scenarios, caching and file names.

Comment: did it work for you both ways, independently from the type? int or string?

Comment: I have no validation scenarios set up except for the defaults. this is a constructed XSD to show the point. I have not tried with the SAXON lib in code yet, this will be my next step.

Comment: I have no problem with validating with Xerces engine.

Comment: I'm using oXygen 19.0 build 2017042020. still confirming the described behaviour on my machine/configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I think I discovered where the problem lies. When using the validation engine Xerces in oXygen the validation passes if the element has the type int. When using the Saxon engine to parse it works either way!

Therefor pretty sure it is **a bug in Xerces**..

[image]